# Can someone explain to me how a function can equal 0?

Tags: javascript

```
function containsPunctuation(word)  
{
    var punctuation = [";", "!", ".", "?", ",", "-"];

    for(var i = 0; i < punctuation.length; i++)
    {
        if(word.indexOf(punctuation[i]) !== -1)
        {
          return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


function isStopWord(word, stopWords) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < stopWords.length; i += 1) 
    {
        var stopWord = stopWords[i];

        if ((containsPunctuation(word)) && (word.indexOf(stopWord) === 0) && (word.length === stopWord.length + 1)) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else if (word === stopWord) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

At the blockquote, how is `containsPunctuation(word) && (word.indexOf(stopWord) === 0`? Can someone explain why they are both equal to zero?

I'm also not sure why `(word.length === stopWord.length + 1)` is used.

Comment: What are the input values?

Comment: this was given ("forest gump, the runner", ["the"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are reading the if statement a little bit incorrectly. Not knowing what the isStopWord function is supposed to do I can't tell you what the `(word.length === stopWord.length + 1)` part is all about.

I can tell you that `(containsPunctuation(word))` is its own boolean value, because that function returns a `true` or `false`.  That part is its own evaluation.

The second part `(word.indexOf(stopWord) === 0)` is also a complete evaluation. That part has nothing to do with the containsPunctuation function. The `indexOf` function returns an integer, so it can equal 0.

The third part `(word.length === stopWord.length + 1)` is checking to see if the length of `word` is one more than the length of `stopWord`.

They are all separate evaluations and because you are using && between them all, they all must evaluate as `true` in order for the code block that follows it to run.

Here are the `indexOf` docs for string and array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

--EDIT--
in light of your comment, my guess for the `(word.length === stopWord.length + 1)` is because the word might contain a punctuation mark that is not included in the `stopWord` so this if check will only return true if the punctuation is at the end of the word because the indexOf check will only return 0 if the stopword starts at the beginning of the word.

Comment: These are the guidelines: 
First write a function containsPunctuation(word) that takes in a single word and returns true if the word contains a punctuation mark. Feel free to use the punctuation array we've given you below.
Second, write a function isStopWord(word, stopWords) that takes in a single word and returns true if it is a stop word. The check will vary depending on if the word contains punctuation or not. Using Array.prototype.indexOf will not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Sean. So `(word.indexOf(stopWord) === 0)` is basically asking if the `stopWord` is at position 0 in `word`?

Comment: Yep, you got it, it would return -1 if it wasn't in the word and a different integer if it were at another position.